# Как программно нарисовать треугольник на canvas в Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, shape

Я пытаюсь создать треугольник на canvas. Но я не уверен, какая сторона равна x1, y1, x2, y2... и т. д. Я сопоставляю свой треугольник с тем, который указан на этом [сайте](https://www.triangle-calculator.com/?what=sss&a=30&b=30&c=59&submit=Solve). Но я вижу разные результаты.

Ниже мой код:

```js
 var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

    // Sides: a = 30   b = 30   c = 59

    var triangle = {
        x1: 30, 
        y1: 0, 
        x2: 0, 
        y2: 59, 
        x3: 30, 
        y3: 59 
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
    ctx.lineTo(triangle.x2, triangle.y2);
    ctx.lineTo(triangle.x3, triangle.y3);
    ctx.lineTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to draw triangle programmatically on canvas in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54805017/7394871) от участника  [@Faiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6804932/faiz).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54805017/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После определения точки, с которой нужно начать рисовать треугольник (в данном случае первая вершина находится в центре холста) и положения второй вершины, вам необходимо вычислить угол между двумя сторонами равной длины. Далее вы можете вычислить положение третьей вершины.

Пожалуйста, прочитайте комментарии в моем коде.

```js
var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
// ширина canvas
let cw = (canvasElement.width = 150),
  cx = cw / 2;
  //высота canvas
let ch = (canvasElement.height = 150),
  cy = ch / 2;
  //your data
let a = 30,
  b = 30,
  c = 59;
  // В этом случае у вас есть равнобедренный треугольник, так как a = b = 30
  // этот треугольник описан в окружности с радиусом = 30
let R = 30;
// вычислить угол между двумя сторонами равной длины
let angle = Math.asin(.5 * 59 /  30);

//нарисуйте описанный круг:
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();


var triangle = {
  //первая вершина находится в центре canvas
  //вы можете решить изменить это.
  x1: cx,
  y1: cy,
  //вторая вершина находится на описанной окружности на уровне 0 радиан, где R - радиус окружности ( a = 30, b=30 )
  //вы можете решить изменить это.
  x2: cx + R,
  y2: cy,
  //calculate the 3-rd vertex
  x3: cx + R * Math.cos(angle),
  y3: cy + R * Math.sin(angle)
};

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x2, triangle.y2);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x3, triangle.y3);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
```

### UPDATE

TC комментирует:

> А если треугольник не равнобедренный? Но равносторонний.

Это более простой случай, так как все стороны и все углы равны. Следующая демонстрация рисует равносторонний треугольник.

```js
var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
// ширина canvas
let cw = (canvasElement.width = 150),
  cx = cw / 2;
  //высота canvas
let ch = (canvasElement.height = 150),
  cy = ch / 2;
  //ваши данные

let L = 60
let a = L,
  b = L,
  c = L;

let R = (L *.5) / Math.cos(Math.PI/6);



//draw the circumscribed circle:
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();


var triangle = {
  //первая вершина находится на описанной окружности в 0 радиан, где R - радиус окружности (R)
  //вы можете решить изменить это.
  x1: cx + R,
  y1: cy,
  //вторая вершина находится на описанной окружности в 2*Math.PI/3 радианах 
  //вы можете решить изменить это.
  x2: cx + R * Math.cos(2*Math.PI/3),
  y2: cy + R * Math.sin(2*Math.PI/3),
  //Рассчитайте положение третьей вершины
  x3: cx + R * Math.cos(4*Math.PI/3),
  y3: cy + R * Math.sin(4*Math.PI/3)
};

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x2, triangle.y2);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x3, triangle.y3);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
```

### UPDATE 2

Нарисовать треугольник, у которого все стороны разные. Для этого мне нужно использовать закон косинусов

> c2 = a2 + b2 - 2*abcos(C)

Где угол `С` противопоставлен стороне `с`.

[решение треугольника](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-triangles.html)

Зная это, можно получить угол `C`:

`let angleC = Math.acos((c*c - a*a - b*b) / (2*a*b) );`

```js
var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
let cw = (canvasElement.width = 150),
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = (canvasElement.height = 150),
  cy = ch / 2;
  
// все стороны разные
let a = 45,
  b = 30,
  c = 59;

let angleC = Math.acos((c*c - a*a - b*b) / (2*a*b) );

 var triangle = {
 //первая вершина находится в центре canvas
 //вы можешь изменить это.
        x1: cx, 
        y1: cy, 
 // the second vertex 
        x2: cx + a, 
        y2: cy, 
 // the 3-rd vertex       
        x3: cx + b*Math.cos(angleC), 
        y3: cy + b*Math.sin(angleC),
    }



ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x2, triangle.y2);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x3, triangle.y3);
ctx.lineTo(triangle.x1, triangle.y1);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806009/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>